# Solaris patch - how to allow user to give parameters?

Tags: bash, solaris

I have to get a parameter provided by the user when a patch is being installed. But when I put this command line into the checkinstall file or preinstall file, I don't get a prompt to provide these parameters.

```
echo put facet name
read facetName
```

My echo for example is redirecting into a log file.

Comment: Solaris checkinstall and preinstall scripts are likely *sourced* under `/bin/sh`.  You might need to use a [`request` script](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7008/ch6advtech-72/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

If standard error is not being redirected, use it:

```
echo -n this is the prompt >&2
read x
```

or, more succintly

```
read -p "this is the prompt: " x
```

If stderr is redirected, you may want to try to use the user's tty directly:

```
echo -n this is the prompt >/dev/tty
read x
```

Comment: Solaris package scripts are likely *sourced* as `/bin/sh` scripts and thus [won't have `read -p`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/read-1.html#scrolltoc).  See http://www.shrubbery.net/solaris9ab/SUNWdev/PACKINSTALL/p12.html#CH3ENHANCEPKG-10289